# how to improve factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, c#-2.0

I have to create a set of object types which are going to be used by the same client. I am thinking of applying factory pattern. But I am new to this design pattern and would like to get advise from some of you guys.

I have MessageTypeA, MessageTypeB and MessageType C. Each message type could be in XML format or normal plain text. Each message type could have 1 or more version as well. 
example,

```
MessageType A in xml format version 1,
MessageType A in xml format version 2,
MessageType A in xml format version 3.

MessageType A in plain text format version 1,
MessageType A in plain text format version 2,
MessageType A in plain text format version 3.

MessageType B in xml format version 1,
MessageType B in xml format version 2,
MessageType B in xml format version 3.

MessageType B in plain text format version 1,
MessageType B in plain text format version 2,
MessageType B in plain text format version 3.
```

Could you suggest me how to apply the factory design pattern to the creation of those objects?

Answer (score 1):

First there is no "Factory" pattern, the known pattern is the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This pattern allows you to create one type of object per Factory method instance and then you pass around your abstract base Factory method and invoke the **single create** method to instantiate whatever it creates.

I think what you need is the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) which is an entirely different animal altogether. In this case each Factory instance **creates a family** of inter-related objects. In your specific case I would model it like this (pseudo-code):

```
// Base abstract Abstract Factory
abstract class MessageAF {
   MsgType createMessageTypeA();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeB();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeC();  
}

// concrete implementation
class XmlFormatVersion1AF extends MessageAF {
   MsgType createMessageTypeA();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeB();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeC();  
}

// concrete implementation
class XmlFormatVersion2AF extends MessageAF {
   MsgType createMessageTypeA();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeB();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeC();  
}

// concrete implementation
class PlainTextFormatVersion1AF extends MessageAF {
   MsgType createMessageTypeA();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeB();  
   MsgType createMessageTypeC();  
}
```

Then in your code base you mostly depend on the type `MessageAF` and you pass the appropriate instance implementation in each case e.g. `PlainTextFormatVersion1AF` to create plain text messages version 1.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in both the Factory Method design pattern described above and the "[Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)" pattern.

Builder is useful if you are converting an abstract description to a concrete representation. The usual example is a structured document, that can be described as elements such as Headline-level-1:"I am the headline", base-text:"I am the content. Several lines go here". This can be converted to several concrete renderings, such as HTML, RTF, PDF...

If your messages fit that model better than the relatively simple family of messages described in Giovanni's answer, you may find use for that pattern. In fact, to my mind his solution is a simplified version of Builder.

Comment: "In fact, to my mind his solution is a simplified version of Builder." My solution is simply the implementation of the Abstract Factory pattern, nothing more nothing less. The Builder Pattern differs completely and it offers the creation of a final object "built by parts" which is **clearly not what the OP is asking for**. A separate remark, make sure to study the actual content before posting uneducated answers?

Comment: Giovanni: There's no need to be rude. Abstract factory pattern is a simplified version of builder. Really it is. Note that I say it is useful if his implementation is more complex than your answer suggests. Quite often the questions posted here are simplified versions of the actual real world problem. I taught DP's at master level at the local U for a couple of years, I'm quite confident in my interpretation. There's often quite a lot of overlap between the patterns, if you study them closely :) I liked your answer, and in fact gave it an upvote.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry. In terms of OO-design many patterns are exactly the same e.g. Proxy and Decorator but conceptually totally different. This is not so much the case of Abstract Factory vs Builder, the applicability and even the structure of the code is different i.e. Builder may well choose not to expose the Object instances generated as part of the intermediate steps whereas the whole point of the Abstract Factory is to expose the instances of the family of inter-related objects. According to what the OP described, I think the best fit is the Abstract Factory.

Comment: Where do you not see that I agree? Yes, your answer applies better to the question exactly as asked. My answer may apply to a more complex reality. I have used both patterns to solve similar problems. Yes, they are very different in terms of class design and relations, but if that's all you see when you look at patterns you are probably missing something.

Comment: I was simply commenting and not implying that you don't agree :) I just wanted to point out that Builder and Abstract Factory are different and not simply a stripped down version of the other. My apparently rude remark for which I apologized is rooted in bumping so many times into people who don't understand the difference but pretend to.

Comment: OK now you have my upvote too, for thinking ahead the OP into the complexity he hasn't realized yet :)

Comment: Thank you. Good conversation!

Comment: btw if you are interested in contributing to an open source DP framework let me know http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net all the contact info is there.